# We should seek common ground while maintaining different opinions. Does this sentence make sense?

Tags: meaning

I am not sure whether "maintain different opinions" can be used here.
Thanks a lot for your corrections or suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please include the research you have done. We like to help those that help themselves.

Comment: This is the essence of democracy -- agreeing on common goals and processes while at the same time having differences of opinion.  It's not easy, but when it works it works well.

Comment: The title and the text are different. You should edit.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically it is fine, but the message is somewhat awkward, because it sounds a bit as if you are saying that there can be common ground even in those areas where the opinions are all different—and it is not clear how that would work.

You probably meant to say something like

*…while respecting each other's differences*.

Or perhaps this:

*We should seek common ground where possible while respecting our differences where it is not.*

Comment: Thank you. So "maintain“ can collocate with "different opinions", but the message delivered in this sentence should be more clearer?

Comment: @KKKKKevin Yes, it is idiomatic to say *maintain different opinions* (see e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Encyclopedia_of_Eastern_Orthodox_Chr/JmFetR5Wqd8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22maintained%20different%20opinions%22&pg=PT583&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22maintained%20different%20opinions%22)). But in the sentence you are asking about, that phrase seems inconsistent with the first part of the sentence.